# Saved time in database differs than what is shown on Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, datetime, fullcalendar

I am working with FullCalendar.io library(ver 3) with MVC. all the events are saved in database. for example I have a event in 9:am but it will be shown on different time on Calendar.
This is my Event in Table

[image]

as you can see it starts on 9:00 am of 2020-09-16 , but I see this time on Calendar. it shows 8:30.
my webHosting is located in USA, But I am in Asia.
This is what I see in FullCalendar

[image]

This is the View:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        var events = [];
        var selectedEvent = null;
        FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();

        function FetchEventAndRenderCalendar() {
            events = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/home/GetEvents",
                success: function (data) {
                   
                    $.each(data, function (i, v) { 
                        events.push({
                            eventID: v.ID,
                            title: v.FullName,
                            firstName: v.FirstName,
                            lastName: v.LastName,
                            phone: v.Phone,
                            description: v.Description,
                            start: moment(v.Start),
                            end: moment(v.End),
                            end: v.End,
                            color: v.ThemeColor,
                            allDay:false,
                            custId:v.CustID
                        });
                        
                    })
                    
                    GenerateCalender(events);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert('failed');
                }
            })
        }

        function GenerateCalender(events) {                
            $('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');              
            $('#calender').fullCalendar({
                locale: 'it',
                contentHeight: 600,
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                },
                eventLimit: true,
                eventColor: '#378006',
                events: events,                   
                eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                    selectedEvent = calEvent;
                    $('#myModal #eventTitle').html(calEvent.lastName + ' ' + calEvent.firstName + '<br>' + calEvent.phone);
                    var $description = $('<div/>');
                    $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Start:</b>' + calEvent.start.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                    if (calEvent.end != null) {
                        $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>End:</b>' + calEvent.end.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                    }
                    $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Description:</b>' + calEvent.description));
                    $('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($description);

                    $('#myModal').modal();
                },
                selectable: true,

                select: function (start, end) {
                    $('#txtFirstName').val('');
                    $('#txtLastName').val('');
                    $("#txtCustomerId").val(0);
                    $("#txtPhone").val('');
                    selectedEvent = {
                        eventID: 0,
                        fullName: '',
                        lastName: '',
                        firstName: '',
                        description: '',
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: false,
                        color: '',
                        Custd: 0
                    };                        
                    modaltest();
                    openAddEditForm();
                },
                editable: true                    
            });        
        }
    }
```

and This is the controller

```
   public JsonResult GetEvents()
    {
        using (SalonEntities dc = new SalonEntities())
        {
          var events = dc.View_EventsFull.ToList();               
          return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
        }
    }
```

why the exact time and date stored on database wouldn't be shown on Calendar?

**---------------------------------
Edited Section
---------------------------------**

This is section that I save data. (in View)

```
  $('#btnSave').click(function () {                            
     var startDate = moment($('#txtStart').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A").toDate();               
     var endDate = moment($('#txtEnd').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A").toDate();
     if (startDate > endDate) {
          alert("Invalid end date");
          return;
      }
      var data = {
          ID: $('#hdEventID').val(),
          FirstName: $('#txtFirstName').val().trim(),
          LastName: $('#txtLastName').val().trim(),
          Phone: $('#txtPhone').val().trim(),
          Start: $('#txtStart').val().trim(),                        
          End:  $('#txtEnd').val().trim(),
          Description: $('#txtDescription').val(),
          ThemeColor: $('#ddThemeColor').val(),
          IsFullDay:false,
          CustID:$('#txtCustomerId').val()
       }
       SaveEvent(data);
     })


      function SaveEvent(data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/home/SaveEvent',
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status) {
                        FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                        $('#myModalSave').modal('hide');
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Failed');
                }
            })
        }
```

And the function which saves the data in Controller is

```
public JsonResult SaveEvent(View_EventsFull e)
{            
   var status = false;
    using (SalonEntities dc = new SalonEntities())
    {
       if (e.ID > 0)
       {
         //Update the event
         var v = dc.Events.Where(a => a.ID == e.ID).FirstOrDefault();                    
         if (v != null)
         {
            v.Start = e.Start;
            v.End = e.End;
            v.Description = e.Description;
            v.IsFullDay = false;
            v.ThemeColor = e.ThemeColor;
            v.CustID = e.CustID;                       
          }
      }
      else
      {                   
         Event eventItem = new Event();
         eventItem.CustID =e.CustID;
         eventItem.Start = e.Start;
         eventItem.End = e.End;
         eventItem.Description = e.Description;
         eventItem.IsFullDay = false;
         eventItem.ThemeColor = e.ThemeColor;
         dc.Events.Add(eventItem);
       }
       dc.SaveChanges();
       status = true;
     }
     return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
    }
```

And this is the Json Created in GetEvents in Controller

> [{"ID":22,"Description":"Test 1","Start":"/Date(1600272000000)/","End":"/Date(1600275600000)/","ThemeColor":"red","IsFullDay":false,"FullName":"Ms Noosh","Phone":"0912","CustID":10,"FirstName":"Noosh","LastName":"Ms"}]

Comment: Is it possible the dates are being output with a timezone offset in the JSON? Please show the JSON generated by your server-side code.

Comment: @ADyson: I added the section in "edited section of the Post", Thank you

Comment: Hm are you using a very old version of MVC? Newer versions will serialise the dates properly to ISO8601 format using JSON.NET instead of that proprietary Microsoft format

Comment: @ADyson: MVC version 5.2.3

Comment: The problem is that `/Date(1600272000000)/` represents the number of ticks since 1970, rather than being a string describing a specific date/time. Therefore when momentJS parses that, it turns it into a date describing the local time in the browser relative to that number of ticks. For me (in the UK), the time comes out as `17:00`, for example. It looks like your server has assumed the timezone is west coast USA, while your browser has assumed it's another one (not sure which one would be half an hour behind that, but you'll know your own timezone).

Comment: Are you wanting the calendar to always show you the times in USA time, no matter where you're located? Or are you wanting the server to interpret all times as being in your local timezone? Or something else?

Comment: @ADyson: Actually this website will be used in Italy. so all the booking time is in Italy Time. is there any way moment ignores the location of the Browser, just shows the saved date and Time ???

Comment: Not when it parses a date of that kind. Like I said, the info it gets simply shows the number of ticks since 1970. It doesn't tell you a precise time, or tell you in what timezone the date was originally entered.

Comment: If you can switch your JSON serialiser in MVC to JSON.NET then it can output plain ISO dates instead - you can google for info about how to do that. Or you could work round it by converting the date properties to `string` type in your model.

Comment: @ADyson: Thank you so much. if you like, post your message as a answer , So I can select it as the answer and score it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this format e.g. `/Date(1600272000000)/` represents the number of ticks since 1970, rather than being a string describing a specific date/time. It doesn't tell you a precise time, or tell you in what timezone the date was originally entered. Therefore when momentJS parses that, it turns it into a date describing the local time in the browser relative to that number of ticks.

If you simply want the application to always treat dates as being in the same timezone, then you could output plain ISO dates in the JSON. If you can switch your JSON serialiser in MVC to JSON.NET then it can do this by default. Or you could work round it by converting the date properties to string type in your model.